# Ruby nested while loop stops early

Tags: ruby, loops

In attempting to iterate over an array of the alphabet and generate all 6-character (alpha only) strings, my iteration seems to end after a single while loop of the most inner-nested loop. Code below. Thoughts?

---

```
alpha = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

x1 = 0
x2 = 0
x3 = 0
x4 = 0
x5 = 0
x6 = 0

while x1<26
    y1 = alpha[x1]
    while x2<26
        y2 = alpha[x2]
        while x3<26
            y3 = alpha[x3]
            while x4<26
                y4 = alpha[x4]
                while x5<26
                    y5 = alpha[x5]
                    while x6<26
                        y6 = alpha[x6]
                        puts y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5 + y6
                        x6 = x6 + 1
                    end
                    x5 = x5 + 1
                end
                x4 = x4 + 1
            end
            x3 = x3 + 1
        end
        x2 = x2 + 1
    end
    x1 = x1 + 1
end
```

---

Edit: It's also VERY likely that I'm overlooking a much simpler way to achieve the desired results. If so, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Oh. My. God. (c)

Comment: Who said that memorable quote that you can write FORTRAN in any language? Or was it Ook language?

Comment: Hey guys, but at least he tried! :)

Comment: Your code isn't working as you'd like because you're not resetting the loop iterators (x1-x6) in each iteration of outer loops. Move x2=0 to after the assignment to y1 and similarly for all the others and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[*?a..?z].repeated_permutation(6).to_a.map &:join
```

Gives FATAL, FAILED TO ALLOCATE MEMORY on my machine,

```
[*?a..?z].repeated_permutation(2).to_a.map &:join
```

works OK.

OK, it is a mistake to call `#to_a` after `#repeated_permutation`, this is how it works:

```
[*?a..?z].repeated_permutation( 6 ).each { |permutation| puts permutation.join }
```

Comment: When I run this, I get: generate.rb:1: undefined method `repeated_permutation' for #<Array:0x107f809c8> (NoMethodError)

Comment: 6 is too much, just count 24 ** 6 #=> 191102976

Comment: @natosennimi: What Ruby version do you use?

Comment: That last one gives the desired result. For some reason #1 & #2 don't run on my Mac but do run correctly on an Ubuntu machine. If you've got a moment, could you briefly explain why my original (as ungainly a mess as it is) doesn't work? EDIT: "ruby 1.8.7" on my Mac and "ruby 2.0.0p0" on remote Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I think that it's because you initialize `x1..x6` with zeroes only at the beginning of your spaceship, while you should initialize them at the beginning of each nested loop.

Comment: @natosennimi: Reinstall your machine with Debian and Ruby 2.0

Comment: I don't think I'm quite ready for a full transition to Linux yet. Soon :)

Comment: @natosennimi: G*d's gonna f*g punish you, it's _GNU Linux_, not _Linux_ :-)))

Comment: Well they're all like Unix :D

Answer (score 4):

To illustrate Ruby way more,

```
loop.inject 'aaaaaa' do |memo|
  puts memo
  break if memo == 'zzzzzz'
  memo.next
end
```

Or simply:

```
( 'aaaaaa'..'zzzzzz' ).each &method( :puts )
```

Comment: Huhh! never seen such styles... nice one

Comment: The second one is great :)

Comment: From 32 lines of ugliness to 1 of simplicity. I like it.

Comment: Note that Boris' other answer is way better, because this will only work with lowercase letters. (Or with only uppercase, but not both)

Comment: @padde: Or with capitalized, `'Aaaaaa'..'Zzzzzz'`. Or with camel cased: `'AaaAaa'..'ZzzZzz'`. Ruby core team surely do like to play.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want? It will generate all unique permutations, but won't double characters (like in "aaaabb")

```
('a'..'z').to_a.permutation(6).to_a
```

Here's a shorter version, for demo purposes:

```
res = ('a'..'c').to_a.permutation(2).to_a 
res # => [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "a"], ["b", "c"], ["c", "a"], ["c", "b"]]
```

Comment: Almost, but yes, I was trying to include doubling characters. Thanks in any case.